# How to make input ( Scanner ) work on Sublime Text 3 when using JAVA?

Tags: java, input, ide, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I just started learning JAVA and Sublime Text 3 was proposed to me as a great compiler for JAVA code. I downloaded it, started programming and set my build system as JavaC. I wanted to create a quick program adding two numbers given by the user and displaying the result but nothing comes up in the "build" section. Do you have any idea to make that work ?

Here is the code I wanna try:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Example
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      int a,b;
      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a number:");
      a=input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter a number:");
      b=input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("sum=" + (a+b));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your problem is two-fold. The `JavaC` build system only compiles code, it doesn't run it. Also, you can't interact with a running program from directly within Sublime; programs that it runs can only display output. So, to do this you need to craft a build system that compiles the code, then opens a command line window and runs the program in there.

Comment: It seems complicated :/ do you know any IDE on which I could work with input ?

Comment: If you're using Java and you're not familiar with it, you probably want something like Eclipse, NetBeans or the Community Edition of IntelliJ. VS Code may also work for this, but I have no experience with it. Note however that IDE's are vastly more complex than text editors are, generally speaking.

Comment: I tried Eclipse and it works fine, thank you for the advice !

Answer (score -1):

For future references on how this windows command line or command prompt in windows works. 
First check if your computer have the JRE (required to run a Java program) and JDK ( required compile and run Java programs) already install to verify this input the text "java -version" and javac -version into the Command Line. If the Javac is already intalls, however, doesn't show in the command line then you need to follow this [sites](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/overview-jdk-10-and-jre-10-installation.htm#JSJIG-GUID-8677A77F-231A-40F7-98B9-1FD0B48C346A) on how to set up the path depending on your OS.